# Excel VBA - the date format changes automatically

Tags: date, excel, vba

I'm trying to enter the Date value by adding a month to the date in Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(17, 3).Value which is 01/10/2011 but format as Oct-11. Then return in Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(17, 4).Value = LDate, to show Nov-11

```
sDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(17, 3).Value   --> this shows 01/10/2011 when I hove over sDate
LDate = DateAdd("m", 1, sDate)                --> this shows 01/11/2011 when I hove over LDate
```

I then want to enter that value 01/11/2011 in to the following cell

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(17, 4).Value = LDate
Selection.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
```

But in the cell it shows  11/01/2011 (Jan-11), why is it doing this and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Minor issue**

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
```

You have not selected anything so this format is placed wherever you left the cursor.

**Major issue**

You have hit the Excel bug that it will interpret dates as being in American (middle endian) format if it can when transferring data to a worksheet.  "1/11/2011" would be "11 Jan 11" to an American so it is to Excel.  "20/11/2011" is not a valid American date so to Excel it is "20 Nov 11".

I can duplicate your problem by declaring sDate and LDate as strings.  `DateAdd` works correctly with strings so LDate is correct but when placed in a cell it is misinterpreted.

I can fix your problem by declaring sDate and LDate as dates:

```
Dim sdate As Date
Dim Ldate As Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
```

Above line is changing the number format. Actually When am running through your steps, I have come across the same issue.

But Number format is doing all this auto change.

Example:

1. While am running the macro, assume that selected cell is `(17,3)`.

   - Before running macro: cell value is `01/11/2012`
   - After running macro: cell value will be changed/formatted as `"Jan-12"`. (Since number format is applied as `"mmm-yy"`, so it consider as `01/11/2012` is consider as `Jan-12`)
2. Second time, if you select the cell `(17,4)`

   - Before running macro: cell value is `2/11/2012`
   - After running macro: cell value will be changed / formatted as `"Feb-12"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying

```
Cells(row2,col2) = Cells(row1,col1)
```

Try this

```
Cells(row1,col1).Copy
Cells(row2,col2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```