# Excel VBA to get Word Document Form Data returning incorrect date format

Tags: vba, excel, date, ms-word

I copied this code to get data from a word document form and put it into an excel spreadsheet and it works great except that the dates are coming in mm/dd/yyyy format.  I need to it be dd/mm/yyyy format.

I tried adding a date picker to the form but that hasn't helped.

Normally I would put the formatting into the VBA code but I am unsure how to do that in this code.  Can it be inserted or can I somehow reformat the date after it comes into the spreadsheet?

The code is in Excel VBA

```
Sub GetFormData()
 'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim CCtrl As Word.ContentControl
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Set WkSht = Sheets("Data")
i = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
    i = i + 1
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
        j = 0
        For Each CCtrl In .ContentControls
            j = j + 1
            WkSht.Cells(i, j) = CCtrl.Range.Text
        Next
    End With
    wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426192/excel-vba-the-date-format-changes-automatically as ths has been answered before

Comment: If you can tell us which range your dates end up in, then you can format that specific range after you have imported all your data...

Comment: What format are the dates appearing in in the Word document? With which language is the text containing the dates formatted? And when you enter dates in Excel they're not in the wrong format? It sounds to me as if Word / Windows is defaulting to US English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to replace

```
WkSht.Cells(i, j) = CCtrl.Range.Text
```

by

```
WkSht.Cells(i, j).FormulaLocal = CCtrl.Range.Text
```